# Mapping a JSON array to a C# DTO array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, entity-framework, dto

Basically what the title says. I have this JSON input:

```
{
    "make": "Opel",
    "model": "Omega",
    "partsId": [
      38,
      102,
      23,
      116,
      46,
      68,
      88,
      104,
      71,
      32,
      114
    ]
  }
```

The **partsId** array is supposed to be an array of DTOs, at least to my understanding.

This is how my Car DTO looks:

```
public class ImportCarDTO
{
    [JsonProperty("make")]
    public string Make { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonProperty("model")]
    public string Model { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonProperty("partsId")]
    public ImportPartCarDTO[] PartsId { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And this is the PartCar DTO:

```
public class ImportPartCarDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The second DTO is going to be filling up records in a mapping table, and I have set the Automapper to ignore the **PartsId** member so I can map it manually. My problem is that I can't convert any of the json array values. I get an **ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to CarDealer.DTOs.Import.ImportPartCarDTO.**

I also tried to research how to use the JsonArray attribute, but I couldn't get it to work. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PartsId` property is a collection of integers (e.g. `List<int>`) not a collection of the class you created here. So just change your class to look like this and delete the `ImportPartCarDTO` class entirely.

```
public class ImportCarDTO
{
    [JsonProperty("make")]
    public string Make { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonProperty("model")]
    public string Model { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonProperty("partsId")]
    public int[] PartsId { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: Guess I shouldn't overthink things so much. Silly oversight on my part, thanks for pointing it out!